# Apex class how to use Map<string,list<Date>> like that?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have samll clarifications how to use  `Map<string,list<Date>>` like that?
My scenario is: I have two fields (Dealer Number and Date) from soql query. Sample values:

```
Date          Dealer number
10/02/2017    10100
15/01/2017    10100
02/02/2017    10100
01/02/2017    10101
05/02/2017    10101
10/01/2017    10102
31/01/2017    10102
```

I want output based on Dealer number.see one Dealer having different dates.this Dealer 10100 having 3 different dates,Month of JAN(count is 1) and Month Feb(count is 2).count is calculated based on same month based. 
output should be:

```
Dealer    FebMonth(Count)    JanMonth(Count)
10100                   2                  1
```

Comment: Please have a look into updated ans, though it is late but could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//first create map to store the dealer no and dates
map<String, List<Date>> mapDealerNoToDates = new map<String, List<Date>>();

//query on your object and get the result
for(your sobject instance :[SOQL QUery here])
{
    //check if the dealer nuber is not null
    if(instance.Dealer_number__c != null )
    {
        //check if map contains the dealer number or not. If not then put into map
        if(!mapDealerNoToDates.containsKey(instance.Dealer_number__c ))
        {
            mapDealerNoToDates.put(instance.Dealer_number__c, new List<Date>());
        }
        //now add dates here
        mapDealerNoToDates.get(instance.Dealer_number__c).add(instance.Date__c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Solution using GROUP BY ROLLUP**

1. Create a Text field `Month__c` and update through Workflow formula. Formula will look this this:

**Formula**

```
CASE(
    MONTH(Date), 1, "January", 
    2, "February", 
    3, "March",  
    4, "April",  
    5, "May",  
    6, "June", 
    7, "July", 
    8, "August", 
    9, "September", 
    10, "October", 
    11, "November", 
    12, "December", "None"
)
```

2. In the apex class, use aggregate query to return and store the results

**Class**

Create a wrapper class with Dealer Name, Month and Count and try to populate records into wrapper class instance from Aggregate query.

```
public List<dealWrapper> dwlst {get;set;}
AggregateResult[] lstDealer = [SELECT Name, Month__c, COUNT(Id) dealCt, GROUPING(Name), GROUPING(Month__c)
                                FROM Dealer__c 
                                GROUP BY ROLLUP(Name, Month__c)
                                ORDER BY GROUPING(Name), GROUPING(Month__c), Name];

for(AggregateResult Obj:lstDealer)
{   
    if(Obj.get('Name')!=null && Obj.get('Month__c') !=null)
    {
        dealWrapper dw = new dealWrapper(Integer.valueOf(Obj.get('Name')), Obj.get('Month__c'), (Integer) Obj.get('dealCt'));
        dwlst.add(dw);      
    }
}

public class dealWrapper
{
    public String DealerNumber{get;set;}
    public String Month {get;set;}
    public Integer dealCount {get;set;}

    public dealWrapper(Integer DealerNumber, String Month, Integer dealCount)
    {
        this.DealerNumber = DealerNumber;
        this.Month = Month;
        this.dealCount = dealCount;
    }
}
```

**SOQL**

```
SELECT Name, Month__c, COUNT(Id) dealCt, GROUPING(Name), GROUPING(Month__c)
FROM Dealer__c 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Name, Month__c)
ORDER BY GROUPING(Name), GROUPING(Month__c), Name
```

**Query Results**

[image: Group By Rollup]

In the visualfore you can easily loop through `<apex:repeat>` and display the records.

[GROUP BY ROLLUP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_rollup.htm) returns the total counts. So you need to eliminate those records where Name or Month are blank.

You could see the power of SOQL query can eliminate all looping for the counts in controller methods.

Comment: Won't that just count the unique months. If there were 2 of month1 the monthCount would be 2 with no indication of the month the count was for. Or am I reading it wrong. You may need groupby rollup

Comment: I will use groupby rollup, my query is wrong which I am changing

Comment: @Eric, please find the updated ans with group by rollup

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over first map and collect the values in required values in second map. Psuedo code here:

```
Map<Date, Integer> mapDateWithDealer =
    new Map<Date, Integer>();
// Assuming your map is filled here

Map<Integer, List<Date>> mapDealerNumberWithDates =
    Map<Integer, List<Date>>();

for(Date d: mapDateWithDealer.keySet()) {
    Integer dealerNumber = mapDateWithDealer.get(d);
    if(!mapDealerNumberWithDates.containsKey(dealerNumber)){
        mapDealerNumberWithDates.put(dealerNumber, new List<Date>());
    }
    mapDealerNumberWithDates.get(dealerNumber).add(d);
}
```

Better would be to form the map directly from query otherwise there​would be an issue if different dealers having same dates. You can still reuse the logic mentioned here​ with soql.

Comment: Hi Rahul, can you possible to store the dates in list<Date>?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet, it will definitely help you to fulfill your requirement : -
my data is like:

```
Date(SLAExpirationDate__c) ------     Dealer number

2017-04-03                             10100
2017-03-02                             10100
2017-03-24                             10100
2017-04-03                             10101
```

After query from object(have used Account object in my case) use below code : -

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> map_dealer = new Map<String,List<Integer>>();
Map<Integer, String> monthMap = new Map<Integer, String>{1 => 'Jan', 2 => 'Feb', 3 => 'Mar', 4 => 'Apr',5 => 'May',6 => 'Jun',7 => 'Jul',8 => 'Aug',9 => 'Sep',10 => 'Oct',11 => 'Nov',12 => 'dec'};
Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> map_result = new Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>();

for(Account acc: lst_account){
if(map_result.containsKey(acc.Dealernumber)){
    Map<String,Integer> temp_map = map_result.get(acc.Dealernumber);

    if(temp_map.containsKey(monthMap.get(acc.Date.month()))){
        Integer incrmonth = temp_map.get(monthMap.get(acc.Date.month()))    ;
        incrmonth++;
        temp_map.put(monthMap.get(acc.Date.month()),incrmonth);
    }   
    else{
        temp_map.put(monthMap.get(acc.Date.month()),1);
    }
    map_result.put(acc.Dealernumber,temp_map);
}   
else{
    Map<String,Integer> temp_map = new  Map<String,Integer>();
    temp_map.put(monthMap.get(acc.Date.month()),1);
    map_result.put(acc.Dealernumber,temp_map);      
    }
}
```

if I print The map **map_result**, result will be like below: -

--Map----{10100={Apr=1, Mar=2}, 10101={Apr=1}}

I think it will help you to achieve you functionality.

Comment: @Revathy,if my answer helps, then accept the answer.